# Roman page numbers in appendix in Lyx

Tags: lyx, roman-numerals, page-numbering

I use LyX 2.0.5.1

I have a report with several chapters and 2 appendices.
I have roman page numbering before chapter 1 (for table of contents, table of figures, etc) and I have arabic page numbering from chapter 1 until the end. However, I would like my 2 appendices to switch to roman page numbering, starting from i (1 in arabic numbering).

This is the code that was generated by LyX for the 1st appendix:

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage newpage
\end_inset
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter
\start_of_appendix
Content of the Appendix 1.
\end_layout
```

I have tried to add the \pagenumbering{roman} in several places near the start of the appendix chapter but it does not work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Insert an ERT with `\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman}` just before you start the appendices.